# Netbeans -- no error message but can't create a project

Tags: netbeans, project

This error is driving me crazy for the past couple of hours. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (clean install). What I did afterwards:

- update everything
- install JDK (using synaptics)
- install netbeans (using synaptics, this is version 7.0.1)

I can start NetBeans just fine but I can't create any project. If I choose "New Project" it keeps saying "Please wait..." under "Categories".

I also tried installing versions of netbeans manually. Starting them as root ... nothing helps! :-(

[image]

Comment: would it annoy you if I said try IntelliJ :-)

Comment: Does it have support for JavaCard? No? OK ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, this is how I solved it:

- Install Oracle's Java version: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux
- Start Netbeans

The error only occurs if using the openjdk ...

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem and came across this answer with nice one line command to fix it:

sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre=6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2 openjdk-6-jre-headless=6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2 icedtea-6-jre-cacao=6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2

https://askubuntu.com/questions/326556/i-cant-start-a-new-project-on-netbeans

Comment: it worked also for me, maybe it's problem with the new version of OpenJDK

Comment: My colleague at work just experienced the same problem on a Xubuntu Vbox after updating and this fixed it.

Comment: Thanks so much, fixed it! Was resorting to creating projects in 7.0, then importing them to 7.3!

Answer (score 0):

To me the best option was, fully remove **openjdk-6-jdk 6b27** and install:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk=6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2 openjdk-6-jre=6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2 openjdk-6-jre-headless=6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2 icedtea-6-jre-cacao=6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2 icedtea-6-jre-jamvm=6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2
```

So the installed packages are the same as when no specific version is selected.